# Opening an Image from a specific file?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, glob

```
import glob
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

filename = glob.glob('/home/ns3/PycharmProjects/untitled1/stego.pgm')
im= Image.open(filename)
(x,y) = im.size
I = np.array(im.getdata()).reshape(y, x)
```

Keeps giving me this error:

im= Image.open(filename)

File "/home/ns3/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2416, in open
    fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read

How can  I open an image from that specific path and use the image as array I?

Comment: Reread the documentation: [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) returns a *list* of names that match the pattern.  Why are you using `glob()` to access a specific file?  Why not `filename = '/home/ns3/PycharmProjects/untitled1/stego.pgm'`?

Comment: so how can I read that image from the specified path @WarrenWeckesser ?

Comment: `filename = '/home/ns3/PycharmProjects/untitled1/stego.pgm'` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that glob.glob() returns a list ([a possibly-empty list of path names that match pathname](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)) and you want a string.

so either insert a [0]

```
import glob
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

filenames = glob.glob('/home/ns3/PycharmProjects/untitled1/stego.pgm')
filename = filenames[0]
im= Image.open(filename)
(x,y) = im.size
I = np.array(im.getdata()).reshape(y, x)
```

or skip glob all together

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

filename = '/home/ns3/PycharmProjects/untitled1/stego.pgm'
im= Image.open(filename)
(x,y) = im.size
I = np.array(im.getdata()).reshape(y, x)
```